# Selenium webdriver - Cannot locate correct Xpath/ID input field

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to find the correct xpath for the html code below and after numerous trials and spending 3 days on the issue I give up and need help. Checking from IDE after recording (execute code) it correctly identifies the webeditbox called accountID but on running test script it fails to write. Please note its within a iframe and is within many classes and div boxes.

IDE: Eclipse Juno
Browser: FireFox
Selenium 2 Webdriver

HTML Code to identify web edit box:
`<input id="accountId" name="accountId" class="text" type="text" value="" maxlength="10">`

Selenium code used:

1) `WebElement AccountID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='accountId']"));
AccountID.sendKeys("1234");`

2)similarly `//*[@id="customPMform"]/p/label`

3)similarly `//*[@id="customPMform"]/p`

I have tried `by.id` as well but no gain. Does anyone know what should be the right selenium code please?

Further HTML CODE:

```
<div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> 
    <form id="customPMform" action="https://webcashier-stg1.egalacoral.com/web/galabingostg1-backup/prepaidcard?p_p_id=prePaidCardDeposit_WAR_prePaidCardbaseVersion60610_INSTANCE_Jl3g&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_id=column-1&amp;p_p_col_count=2&amp;_prePaidCardDeposit_WAR_prePaidCardbaseVersion60610_INSTANCE_Jl3g_action=submit" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;"> 
        <input id="methodCode" name="methodCode" type="hidden" value="PrePaidCard"> 
        <input id="depositSuccessUrl" name="depositSuccessUrl" type="hidden" value="/ppcdepositsuccess"> 
        <input id="quickSuccessUrl" name="quickSuccessUrl" type="hidden" value="/ppcquickdepositsuccess"> 
        <h2><span class="text-msg" name="prePaidCardDeposit.title">PrePaid Card</span></h2> 
        <p class="form"> 
            <label for="accountId">
                <span class="text-msg" name="prePaidCardDeposit.accountId">Account ID</span>
            </label>
            <input id="accountId" name="accountId" class="text" type="text" value="" maxlength="10"> 
        </p> 
    </form>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`By.xpath("//input[@id='accountId']")` should let you select the correct element

`//[@id='accountId']` doesn't specify a tag and could be corrected as above

`//*[@id="customPMform"]/p/label` select the label, and you can't send keys to a label element

`//*[@id="customPMform"]/p` select the `<p>` element. Same thing as above

Comment: Apologies for this but we have already tried "By.xpath("//input[@id='accountId']")" and it still doesn't work. When I use the sendKeys function it doesn't do anything to that xpath

I have run out of solutions and I am not sure on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in **iframe** you should switch the control to iframe before accessing any element within that.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameName/Id/index");
driver.findElement(By.id("accountId")).sendKeys("1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, if you right click the element and choose Copy XPath, that may give you what you are looking for.

Comment: //*[@id="accountId"] Is the XPath but when I locate this ID it doesn't work. What other ways around is there?

Also  `p id="aui_3_2_0_1136" class="form">
<label for="accountId">
<span class="text-msg" name="prePaidCardDeposit.accountId">Card Number</span>
</label>
<input id="accountId" class="text" type="text" maxlength="10" value="" name="accountId">`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue searching for field with name="cardNumber". I suppose there are some field name masks selenium prevent to be found.

The workaround in my case was to use absolute position. It may be the following for your issue:

```
//form[@id='customPMform']//input[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Frames should be handled as separate pages and you should switch to that frame before finding and using any web element of a frame.

As a good practise, developers should tell you the numbers of frames, flash elements ,  applets used on a page in advance.

Answer (score 0):

best way is, use selenium ide find the xpath and copy the same into your code. because sometimes there will be multiple inputs and if you make use of firebug it may not give you the correct xpath. (example : using firebug the xpath generated might be .//*[@id='title'] but when captured using selenium ide it might be (.//*[@id='title'])[2]). 
you can also choose to generate absolute xpath and try.